# (HandTrackingModule) 'NoType has no object len()

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

So recently i started to learn python, i learned the basic and found an interesting project involving opencv from a youtube channel freecodecamp.org which is hand tracker, i write the bare minimum of the code and decided to write the module. Halfway up the programming process i tried to run the project to see if there is any error and it says

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

here is where i think the error takes place

```
    def findPosition(self, frame, handNomor = 0, draw=True):

    landmarklist = []

    if self.result.multi_hand_landmarks:
        tanganku = self.result.multi_hand_landmarks[handNomor]

        for id, lm in enumerate(tanganku.landmark):
            #print(id, lm)
            h, w, c = frame.shape
            cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
            #print(id, cx, cy)
            landmarklist.append([cx, cy, id])
            if draw:
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx, cy), 2, (195, 26, 195), cv2.FILLED)

        return landmarklist


def main():
ptime = 0
ctime = 0
detector = handDetector()
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)



while True:
    start, frame = camera.read()
    frame = detector.findhands(frame)
    landmarklist = detector.findPosition(frame)
    #print(landmarkList)
    if len(landmarklist) != 0:
        print(landmarklist[4])

    ctime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (ctime - ptime)
    ptime = ctime
```

Could you please point my mistake?

Comment: When you post an error, please also post the line where the error occured. It would be best if you post both the stack trace and also mark the offending line with a comment (something like `# HERE`). Assuming the `len` found in your snippet is the right one, `self.result.multi_hand_landmarks` was falsy, in which case there was no `return` statement, and Python implicitly returns `None`. Make sure you return a meaningful value in `else` case as well, or check if `landmarklist` is `None` before you check its length.

Comment: looks like `return ...` is indented so that it's within the `if` block, try moving it back a tab-stop to bring it outside the `if`

Comment: personal advice if you are new to python then learn basics first after that jump on computer vision.

Comment: Also, just search for the error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+object+of+type+%27NoneType%27+has+no+len%28%29

Comment: Can u fix indentation in def main(): function?  Also this too def findPosition